# How can I systematically verify that I can hear correctly words belonging to a vocabulary list?

Tags: vocabulary, listening

I've been studying the Chinese HSK6 vocabulary, and the majority of words I can read correctly.  What worries me is that sometimes (often?) when I'm listening, I don't recognize certain words.  If they were written down, I know precisely what they mean, but if I hear them, my mind is blank.  On the exam, I won't have time to stop and think about which word it is.

I know I could go to something like [YouGlish](https://youglish.com/chinese), input the words one-by-one and watch to videos.  This would provide listening practice, but wouldn't be a true test since I know that the word in advance.

Importantly, there are [2500 words](https://github.com/glxxyz/hskhsk.com/blob/main/data/lists/HSK%20Official%20With%20Definitions%202012%20L6%20freqorder.txt), so any approach needs to be practical in terms of time.

**Question**: How can I systematically verify that I can hear correctly words belonging to a vocabulary list?

At the moment, I'm thinking of seeking out a list of example sentences, randomize the order, use text-to-speech, then write down the sentences I hear.  But perhaps there are better methods for this task.

I'm primarily interested in Chinese, but I'm expecting the methods would likely apply to any language.